# Convert java.io.BufferedReader to Json object

Tags: java, groovy

I have a rest endpoint in a groovy class with a method signature like this....

```
public PostMyResponse postMyRequest(Reader arg0) throws Exception {
```

`Reader` is a `java.io.BufferedReader`. On my post request I pass in json.

If I do something like this I can see the parameters (Note: I'm aware that this is printing out strings in a java style loop. It's not what I am after)....

```
int value=0;

// reads to the end of the stream
while((value = arg0.read()) != -1)
{
    // converts int to character
    char c = (char)value;

    // prints character
    System.out.println(c);
```

What I am after is a way to convert the `java.io.BufferedReader` to a nice Json object using groovy and then to read properties from the json object?

thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Serialize & Deserialize bean to json with Groovy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27250386/serialize-deserialize-bean-to-json-with-groovy)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just do:

```
def result = new JsonSlurper().parse(reader)
```

Then `result` will be a representation (maps and lists) of whatever JSON was in your reader